# What am I actually missing?

Tags: batteries, parallel, series

[image]

While I was reading a physics textbook, I've seen something unclear, which is about ΔV. What does this book actually mean by ΔV? It seems like it is potential difference, right? However, the thing I'm trying to get is why it is potential difference, assume that there are two batteries connected in series or parallel, How should we analyze the circuit? Honestly, I didn't see anything related to parallel/series batteries, Why? On other hand, it should've explained what to do when there are batteries connected in series or parallel. What am I missing?

Wishing My Kindest Regards!

---

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: The information is probably obvious from the figure.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany that would be as you said. However, this textbook should've explained what to do when there are batteries in parallel or series. Otherwise, thinking on If I'm missing something while searching. Does ΔV mean potential difference of battery or something?

Comment: Is there someone who's able to help? :)

Comment: Delta signifies difference, and delta-V signifies a voltage difference, between two nodes in a circuit, two places where a voltmeter probe can be pressed to make a measurement.   So, delta-V indicates a voltage difference for some (any) two-terminal component or subcircuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you have current flow anywhere in a circuit it creates delta-v, which means *differential voltage*. Any 2 points in a circuit with current flowing will create a delta-v. Resistors and even a long copper trace create a voltage drop, also called delta-v.

Current flow is constant in a single loop of power source, resistance and load, but using a voltmeter you will find a delta-v across any 2 points in the circuit.

All delta-v's in series add together to create a large delta-v. Any resistance via resistors or wire length create delta-v that adds up to the power source voltage/potential.

The batteries are also delta-v objects, but they create potential with chemicals.

Comment: Does it mean that we will sum up the batteries if they're connected in series?

Comment: Parallel batteries sum the current that can be drawn from them, but maintain the same voltage. Batteries in series add their voltages together but supply the same current as one battery.

Comment: So did it explain what you said by delta V?

Comment: Yes. I did not contradict myself. Poke into circuits with a voltmeter and find out these things.

Comment: Oh, I mean by Delta V = delta V_1 = delta V_2 However, it doesn't seem like It explained, why? It is just potential difference, isn't it?

Comment: @Busi \$\Delta V\ne \Delta V_1\$!

Comment: We can say that Delta V =  Delta V_1 + Delta V_2...

Comment: Yes, your text says so.

Comment: Yeah but I want to know what to do when there are two batteries connected in series. Do we explain that by using this formula or not? In my perspective, it just explains potential difference (sorry I don't have enough knowledge).

Comment: I already answered that question in an above comment.

Comment: Yes, but am asking for my textbook. Do we explain it by using Delta V = Delta V_1 + Delta V_2...?

Comment: It is delta-v + delta-v.

Comment: It's potential difference lol, How?

Comment: Yes, if the word 'potential' works for you.

Comment: The thing I'm still trying to get is why it explains this topic above the resistance. There should be anything related to parallel/series batteries.

Comment: All delta-v's in series add together to create a large delta-v.

Comment: Oh, now I got it! Does delta-v refer to battery? I mean do we show it by delta-v?

Comment: am confused again, wow lol! It says ''across the resistance''

Comment: Glad to help. In series circuit current is the same at all points. but delta-v (from whatever creates it) adds up to equal source voltage.

Comment: Yeah but It didn't explain what to do when there are batteries connected in series. That's what I'm having trouble with. On other hand, it would explain it by delta-v. Can you explain what we should get from delta-V?

Comment: First I should know what this ''delta-v'' means, I think that's why im still not getting it. Does delta-v refer to battery?

Comment: I added a third paragraph to help out. You need to think about all things being relative. Delta-v is a voltage drop (potential) across any resistance. In series they add up.

Comment: But it doesn't explain that we've to add up the batteries, seems like just given a potential difference formula. Or am I wrong again?

Comment: The batteries are also delta-v objects, but they create potential with chemicals.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Busi, if you can't comprehend explanations of the most basic abstraction of electricity even when explained from all different angles, close the book and go back playing pokemon.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the figure is not very clear. Delta-V is the voltage across the respective resistor. So by Kirchoff's voltage law the drops across each component add up to zero, taking polarity into account.

There is only one battery, as is clearly shown, but two resistors in series. Please add the figure to the question.

Comment: That's not the answer I'm looking for. It doesn't matter if I've attached figure or not. The thing is to get what ΔV means.

Comment: You're being very belligerent for someone who is looking for help.

Comment: Definelity not :) just mentioning what I'm having trouble with. If I seem like rude, my apologies.

Comment: "The thing is to get what ΔV means." spehro answerd "Delta-V is the voltage across the respective resistor". I don't get how that can *not* be a good answer!

Comment: (And the request to add the picture is to make your question a better question.)

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I still didn't get what it means.

Comment: Figure has been attached. see the new edit if necessary.